# How can i install a network scanner to Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, scanner, scanning

I have a multi-purpose printer (scanner/fax/printer/copier). Samsung M267x 287x.
I have added it as a printer in  Ubuntu 14.04. How can I add it as a scanner to Ubuntu?

Comment: If it's alrady installed and supported you should just launch Simple Scan and try it.

Comment: It just said not scanner is connected.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid this is not the answer you are looking for, but according to [this site](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-SAMSUNG), your (scanner) model is not supported. Printer drivers can be found on more than one site, but no scanner drivers for your model, at least not in a Linux-native way.

```
M267x 287x Series   USB     0x04e8/0x3461   Unsupported
```